# Base Table or View not found:1146 in symfony3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

So I had some issues with my PC few days ago . I used the Sytem Restore to fix them.

Everything is ok now, but I have some issues with my `symfony` project.

Indeed, some tables don't seem to "exist" anymore for `symfony` , and others are working perfectly.

I don't know why, but when I want to persist or use these tables I have this error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base Table or view not found:1146
>   Table'Symfony.tablename'doesn't exist

The Entity is still there and I can found the corrupted tables on `mysql` . How to fix it ?
thanks

[image: bug2]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo
I know how to fix this issue now .

This solution apply for those who are using symfony 3  (framework).

First you need to delete your table in mysql with this command (database = symfony) .

```
DROP TABLE yourtablename;
```

Now re-generate your entities again via this command

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:entities YourBundleNameBundle
```

Update your entities schema on mysql

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump -sql
```

Now force the Schema and your tables should be back again

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: you saved me a lot of time !

Comment: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump -sql does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do these tables are listed in information_schema ? I doubt they disappeared from it, but we never know / you can check that with this query :

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

You should also give a try to repair methods listed on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html). Is the symfony mysql user in parameters the same than the one you use to access them from your GUI ? If not, have a look at your permissions too for the Symfony User.

Dumping your database and importing it again should do the job in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response , i have found the solution .